# Prevent Form Resubmit

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

I've been looking for this answer for a couple weeks now but many other questions/answers don't fit my project or simply don't work.

Let me explain my project.
It is a simple View Page which on page load it would set the Text to different fields throughout the page. On the bottom I have a container with buttons which control which div is displayed in the container. On each click of the button, I run some code to set data sources to grid views or fill fields with text. I noticed when I click F5 to refresh the page I get that pesky "form resubmission" popup which will cause the last button click such as appending a note to a listview to be duplicated.

Here is some code to understand what I am doing

**HTML(Not complete, just necessary to understand my question)**

```
<td style="vertical-align: top;" class="Flow-Sub-Menu">
    <asp:Button ID="Button_Sub_Menu_Financial" runat="server" Text="Financial Info" OnClick="Button_Sub_Menu_Financial_Click" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button_Sub_Menu_Indemnitors" runat="server" Text="Indemnitors" OnClick="Button_Sub_Menu_Indemnitors_Click" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button_Sub_Menu_Court" runat="server" Text="Court Info" OnClick="Button_Sub_Menu_Court_Click" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button_Sub_Menu_Forfeiture" runat="server" Text="Forfeiture Info" OnClick="Button_Sub_Menu_Forfeiture_Click" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button_Sub_Menu_Collaterals" runat="server" Text="Collaterals" OnClick="Button_Sub_Menu_Collaterals_Click" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button_Sub_Menu_Notes" runat="server" Text="Notes" OnClick="Button_Sub_Menu_Notes_Click" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button_Sub_Menu_Documents" runat="server" Text="Documents" OnClick="Button_Sub_Menu_Documents_Click" />
</td>

<div id="Div_Sub_Menu_Notes" runat="server" visible="false">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4" style="min-width: 550px;">
            <div class="Flow-Box">
                <div class="Flow-Box-Content" style="height: 440px; overflow-y: scroll;">
                    <asp:ListView ID="LV_Notes" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="ItemPlaceHolder" DataKeyNames="Bond_Note_ID" OnPagePropertiesChanging="LV_Notes_PagePropertiesChanging" OnItemCommand="LV_Notes_ItemCommand">
                        <LayoutTemplate>
                            <table style="width: 500px; background-color: white;">
                                <tr id="ItemPlaceHolder" runat="server"></tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2">
                                        <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager_Notes" runat="server" PagedControlID="LV_Notes" PageSize="3">
                                            <Fields>
                                                <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Link" ShowFirstPageButton="false" ShowPreviousPageButton="true"
                                                   ShowNextPageButton="false" />
                                                <asp:NumericPagerField ButtonType="Link" />
                                                <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Link" ShowNextPageButton="true" ShowLastPageButton="false" ShowPreviousPageButton="false" />
                                            </Fields>
                                        </asp:DataPager>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </LayoutTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2" style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;">
                                    <div style="border: 2px solid grey; height: 75px; padding: 5px;">
                                        <%# Eval("Note") %>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="padding-left: 10px;" <%# (Eval("Document_ID").ToString() != "" ?  "" : "hidden=\"hidden\"") %>>
                                    <label>Document Attached : <%# Eval("Document_Title").ToString() %></label>
                                </td>
                                <td style="text-align: right; padding-right: 10px;" <%# (Eval("Document_ID").ToString() != "" ?  "" : "hidden=\"hidden\"") %>>
                                    <asp:Button ID="Button_View_Document" runat="server" Text="View/Download Document" CommandName="View_Document" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Document_ID")%>' />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="text-align: left; padding-left: 10px;">
                                    <div>
                                        <%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("Created_DateTime")).ToShortDateString() + " " + Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("Created_DateTime")).ToShortTimeString() %>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td style="text-align: right; padding-right: 10px;">
                                    <div>
                                        <%# Eval("Full_Name") %>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2" style="height: 20px; border-top: 4px solid #009900;"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:ListView>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4" style="min-width: 500px;">
                <div class="Flow-Box">
                    <div class="Flow-Box-Label">
                        New Note
                    </div>
                    <div class="Flow-Box-Content">
                        <table class="Flow-Box-Table">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <textarea id="TextArea_New_Note" runat="server" style="width: 400px; height: 150px;"></textarea>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Button ID="Button_Append_New_Note" runat="server" OnClick="Button_Append_New_Note_Click" Text="Append Note" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**C# Codebehind**

```
protected void Button_Sub_Menu_Notes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    resetSubMenuButtons();
    Button_Sub_Menu_Notes.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange;
    Div_Sub_Menu_Notes.Visible = true;
    string bondID = Request.QueryString["BondID"];
    bindNotes(bondID);
}

protected void bindNotes(string bondID)
{
    DataTable dt = Common_Functions.GetData("SELECT * FROM View_Bond_Notes_With_Name WHERE Bond_ID='" + bondID + "' ORDER BY Created_DateTime DESC");
    LV_Notes.DataSource = dt;
    LV_Notes.DataBind();
}

protected void LV_Notes_PagePropertiesChanging(object sender, PagePropertiesChangingEventArgs e)
{
    (LV_Notes.FindControl("DataPager_Notes") as DataPager).SetPageProperties(e.StartRowIndex, e.MaximumRows, false);
    string bondID = Request.QueryString["BondID"];
    bindNotes(bondID);
}

protected void LV_Notes_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (String.Equals(e.CommandName, "View_Document"))
    {
        ListViewDataItem dataItem = (ListViewDataItem)e.Item;
        string documentID = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
        Session["BondDocumentID"] = documentID;
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "openDocument", "window.open('/FileServing/Bond_Document_Server.aspx');", true);
    }
}

protected void Button_Append_New_Note_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string bondID = Request.QueryString["BondID"];
    string UserID = Request.Cookies["UserID"].Value;
    string newNote = TextArea_New_Note.Value;
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newNote))
    {
        return;
    }
    cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Bond_Notes " +
        "(Bond_ID, Created_DateTime, Created_By, Note) " +
        "VALUES " +
        "(@Bond_ID, @Created_DateTime, @Created_By, @Note)", conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Bond_ID", bondID);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Created_DateTime", DateTime.Now);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Created_By", UserID);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Note", (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newNote) ? (object)DBNull.Value : newNote));
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
    TextArea_New_Note.Value = "";
    bindNotes(bondID);
}
```

So when the user clicks "Button_Append_New_Note", the code will fire to run the sqlcommand and then refreshes the ListView by calling the "bindNotes(bondID)". If the user clicks F5 or hits refresh for whatever reason, they are resubmitting that form and add duplicates. I've read many solutions to redirect to the same page, this will not work in my case since the div would be hidden again and I would prefer the Notes div to stay visible so the user can see their new note in the listview. I also prefer not to have an sql check to look for a duplicate and prevent an insert since I may want the user to insert duplicates if they chose to at another time, but the user would manually type in the duplicate.

Any recommendations or suggestions on how to avoid the form resubmission?

**Also please no criticizing on the code, I am looking for answers, not a lecture on why its bad to build an SQL sentence with inline string addition. I will correct and optimize these faults eventually.**

**If you found my solution elsewhere, please ensure it would work in my case cause I have found my same question many times, but not with my scenario.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: wrap your `asp:listView` with `asp:updatePanel` and set `trigers` to your buttons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you probably know, ASP.NET Web Forms send *POST* requests back to the server and then re-render the `Page` in the same request. This is why we see the form re-submission message when we click "reload".

To avoid this issue, we should employ the post-then-redirect pattern used by many web applications. Here's a quick overview:

1. A user clicks a button which submits the form as a *POST* request.
2. The server receives the request and saves the data.
3. The server issues a *redirect* response along with any needed state.
4. The browser receives the redirect and loads the appropriate page by sending a *GET* request.

Because we redirect the browser to a new (or the same) location, this clears the *POST* data from the previous request so we can hit "reload" without re-submitting the same data again. The URL that we redirect to should contain only the data needed for the server to interpret what to display on the page. This pattern provides a durable way to maintain state between requests in HTTP.

To apply this to the Web Form in the question, we need to change some assumptions about how the page loads. Instead of binding the notes to the page after running each *POST* action, we'll redirect the user first, and then bind the notes:

```
protected void Button_Append_New_Note_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string bondID = Request.QueryString["BondID"];

    // Save the new note...

    Response.Redirect("http://example.com/Page.aspx?BondID=" + bondID);
}
```

Then, when the browser loads the redirect:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        bindNotes(Request.QueryString["BondID"]); 
    }
}
```

We'll need to change each of the post-back methods to use this pattern. Some of the methods may need to add additional parameters to the redirect URL that the page reads to configure the display.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I had the weekend off and didn't notice. I see what you mean and it would work perfectly but I wanted to avoid configuration of the display state. Depending on which submenu they decide to click, I do a lot of visible=true/false on some divs. I would have to store a state and then show/hide the appropriate divs. This can mean added dozens of display configurations. I wanted to avoid this altogether, but your answer would work perfectly if I wasn't so stubborn on implementing a display configuration system. Thanks for your time and effort. Greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @Athanasios - I hear you--it's a lot of state to keep track of manually. Unfortunately, this is the most robust approach when we want to do full server-side rendering. It also creates URLs that users can easily bookmark, share, and return to. Beware of server-side state tracking that can pollute the session and create hard-to-find bugs. Alternatively, we can manage this state client-side with JavaScript and AJAX. ASP.NET provides [some tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001.aspx) that may help. However, the question suggests that we're invested in the server-side style.

Comment: I marked it as correct. You are correct with your answer but it doesn't necessarily fit my project since I explained that I specifically did not want to redirect to the page. Since my users would show/hide different divs depending on what they do and I did not want to implement some sort of state saving feature to know which div to show/hide and what databinding functions to run with what parameters. This would be way too time consuming.

Answer (score 5):

This is quite easy and blocks the pop up asking for form resubmission on refresh once the form is submitted. Just place this line of javascript code at the footer of your file and see the magic.

```
<script>
if ( window.history.replaceState ) {
  window.history.replaceState( null, null, window.location.href );
}
</script>
```